How do I generify typing of keyword arguments of instance method in Python?
Inspired by PEP 692 – Using TypedDict for more precise **kwargs typing, I want to create a class C with a generic T, which defines the types of the keyword arguments for some instance method f.
Currently I have to override the signature of f manually (in a slightly illegal way):
class C:
    def f(**kwargs: Any):
        ...

class DTypes(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: str

class D(C):
    def f(**kwargs: Unpack[DTypes]):
        super().f(**kwargs)

class ETypes(TypedDict):
    a: str
    b: int

class E(C):
    def f(**kwargs: Unpack[ETypes]):
        super().f(**kwargs)

I have no need for D or E to be a sub-type of C, but simply want them to share the functionality of f, with different types for kwargs, with out having to override f many times.
I am using python3.11.
I've tried using TypeVars bounded by TypedDict, however, this does not seem to work. (I assume due to invariance of TypedDicts).
T = TypeVar('T', bound=TypedDict)  # Pyright:  "TypedDict" can not be used in this context.
class Foo(Generic[T]):
    def f(**kwargs: Unpack[T]):  # Pyright:  Expected TypedDict type argument for Unpack.
        ...

class BarTypes(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: str

class Bar(Foo[BarTypes]):
    pass

class BazTypes(TypedDict):
    a: str
    b: int

class Baz(Foo[BazTypes]):
   pass

Additionally, I've also played around with metaclasses, but I couldn't get that to work.

This looks like a limitation of the type checker. I can't think of a workaround. Your best bet is probably posting this to the Python mailing lists. (mypy also rejects your second code snippet, so this seems like a limitation in Python rather than a bug in Pyright.)

"I have no need for D or E to be a sub-type of C, but simply want them to share the functionality of f": Sounds like you are better off using dependency injection.

@InSync you are definitely right about that! Unfortunately, I think that I would still need to define the signature of the method f over and over.
The real world use-case is an APIResourceRepository (Foo), with specific classes for different API resources (Bar and Baz), that share functionality (CRUD), with varying fields.
A simple solution is obviously DTOs, but I hoped to be able to leverage the flexibility of the language.
